# Date parsing exception while converting from date string to date

Tags: java, date

How to parse this date string in java

> "2020-06-12T00:00:00.000+00:00"

I tried the following code :

```
public static String convertToStandardDateString(String date) {
        // 2020-06-12T00:00:00.000+00:00
        String resDate = null;
        try {
            DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+'X");
            Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(date);
            resDate = sdf.format(parsedDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return resDate;
    }
```

I am getting the `ParsingException` with the above code.

Comment: Ditch the quoted `+`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Your formatting pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+'X"` has quotes around the `+` which means "expect but ignore this text". You should *not* ignore that character, as it is a crucial part of the offset-from-UTC, with `+` meaning hours-minutes-seconds ahead of UTC and `-` meaning behind. Furthermore, no need to define a custom formatting pattern. The `java.time.OffsetDateTime` class can parse that string by default, as seen in [Answer by Deadpool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62363299/642706).

Answer (score 5):

Stop using the deprecated [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and start using the java-8 [date-time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) api. The date string you have represents date time with offset, so you can parse it directly into [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html)

> A date-time with an offset from UTC/Greenwich in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00.

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-06-12T00:00:00.000+00:00");
```